# CSS Disabled Textbox Styling Problem Using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have a Text Box that is disabled and is using bootstrap to style it. However, there is a small little white space on the right side of the Text Box that appears only in Chrome. I've tried a few things to remove it, but it persists. I've tried it in Opera, IE, and Firefox and it's fine. This only happens in Chrome. Any ideas?

I've changed the bootstrap "form-control" border radius to zero as shown here:

```
.form-control {
    border-radius: 0.1rem;
}
```

And I've also changed the side bar with as shown in the screen shot below.

For some reason the combination of the two causes a white space.

[image]

Comment: make display:inline-block; or share us the code to check.

Comment: That is the code. also, after more testing i found one other item that is impacting it. I've added it in as an edit